# SimpleCV: How can I get the resoultion of a Logitech cam?

Tags: webcam, camera

Is there a way to alter the resolution of my Logitech usb cam (C930e) in [SimpleCV](http://www.simplecv.org/)?
I seem to get the stream only in 640x480.